# How to Interpret NLTK Brill Tagger Rules

Tags: nlp, nltk, part-of-speech

For the generated Brill Tagger Rule:

```
Rule('016', 'CS', 'QL', [(Word([1, 2, 3]),'as')])
```

I know:
`'CS'` is subordinating conjunction
`'QL'` is qualifier

I guess:
`[(Word([1, 2, 3]),'as')]` means the condition of the rule. It stands for the word `'as'` appear as the first, second or third position before the target word. Target word is word that is going to be tagged by POS tag.

I do not know:
What is the meaning for `'016'`?
How to interpret the rule as a whole?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for the rules is [here.](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tbl.html#nltk.tbl.rule.Rule)
`016` would be the the `templateid`, i.e. the template that was used to create the rule.
You can also get a description for the rule:

```
q = Rule('016', 'CS', 'QL', [(Word([1, 2, 3]),'as')])
q.format('verbose')
'CS -> QL if the Word of words i+1...i+3 is "as"'
```

In this case it is actually the words that come *after* the target word. (Indicated by `i+1...`)